# Aplicação para marcação de ponto!

Tags: c#, c, c++

Boa tarde gente, tudo certo?

Estou querendo desenvolver uma aplicação aqui para o trabalho. 
Hoje onde trabalho, temos os funcionários corporativos (ficam entre todas as unidades da empresa). E no fim do mês eles devem entregar uma folha de ponto completa com todos os dias e horários certinhos.
Pra facilitar e até modernizar também, pensei em fazer essa aplicação, na qual ficaria no notebook do funcionário, onde ele digitaria uma ID e uma senha (talvez) o programa pegaria a data/hora de acordo com a hora do computador, e no fim do mês, o funcionário pudesse clicar em algo semelhante a ENVIAR e o mesmo, enviasse toda a folha do mês para o e-mail do departamento pessoal e do gestor da área.

Então, gostaria de saber de quem entende... Qual linguagem seria a melhor pra essa aplicação, quais "buracos" essa ideia pode ter, etc...

Reforçando, que não quero um feito. Quero fazer eu mesmo, por ser uma aplicação simples e até mesmo para agregar conhecimento pra mim no currículo e na empresa.

Desde já agradeço. :)

Comment: Perguntas cujo as respostas possam se basear em opinião não são o esperado para se discutir aqui. Visite este endereço e verifique [a respeito de quais tópicos é possível fazer perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: E então o usuário altera o horário da máquina para bater o ponto na hora que quiser?

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde tspereirarj,

Existe um grande problema na lógica da sua aplicação: o usuário poderá livremente manipular as informações que serão registradas simplesmente alterando a data/hora do sistema operacional, podendo inclusive bater ponto de forma retroativa, exemplo: eu falto a semana toda mas na hora de fazer o login no programa de ponto eu altero datas e horas pra fazer os registros tendo apenas o mínimo cuidado de deixar na ordem as datas. Não será interessante para a empresa ter que lidar com isso.

Uma sugestão que eu dou seria pegar a data e hora de um **servidor**(caso a sua empresa trabalhe com um sistema web, por exemplo), ao qual os usuários não terão acesso as configurações, e fazer os registros a partir dele.

Quanto à linguagem de programação:

Não existe isso de linguagem "Melhor" ou "Pior", existem linguagens e suas ferramentas, algumas servem melhor pra determinadas finalidades. Você não tenta cavar um buraco usando uma colher ou comer usando uma motosserra, mas não quer dizer que sejam ferramentas ruins.

**A linguagem a ser utilizada depende, dentre outras coisas, do**:

- **Seu domínio sobre ela**:

Não adianta tentar utilizar uma linguagem que você não conhece, a menos que só ela possa resolver sua demanda, pois você teria que dispor de tempo para estudar e praticar.

- **Da forma que sua aplicação vai funcionar**:

Como eu disse anteriormente, existem diferentes linguagens com diferentes ferramentas e você precisa identificar de quais ferramentas você precisa pra escolher a linguagem certa.

- **Tempo que você tem pra desenvolver**:

No caso de ser algo a ser feito "para ontem", você pode, por exemplo, escolher linguagens focadas na agilidade de desenvolvimento. Ruby, por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraços